# How to disable DefaultSecurityFilterChain in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring, security, filter, spring-boot, chain

In my Spring Boot application, I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)
        throws Exception 
    {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            // various GET/POST path enable rules, none of which would enable access to default ones (see log below)
            ...
            // finally, deny everything else
            .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
            ...
    }
}
```

At startup, the log shows:

```
2016-01-29 13:20:49.379  INFO 8044 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
```

and I can access, for example, `localhost:8080/blah/favicon.ico` even though I would expect it to be blocked.

I tried to follow recommendations in [Security configuration with Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633477/security-configuration-with-spring-boot) and [Spring Security exclude url patterns in security annotation configurartion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767205/spring-security-exclude-url-patterns-in-security-annotation-configurartion).

Per docs at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security, I also tried setting `security.ignored` to various paths, as well as annotating the above class with `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)`, all to no avail.

Is there a simple way to disable the `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` so that it does not add these ignored (insecure) paths for common static resource locations?

If not, what is the proper configuration, either in Java or in `application.properties`, to disable these paths?

---

OK, so there are two ways to do it:

In `application.properties`, set `security.ignored=none`.

Or, create the following class:

```
@Component
public class CustomSecurityProperties extends SecurityProperties {
    public CustomSecurityProperties() {
        // the default list is empty
        List<String> ignoredPaths = getIgnored();
        ignoredPaths.add("none");
    }
}
```

A hint for the magic `none` came from lines 121-130 of `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java

Either solution still leaves the following in the log:

```
2016-01-29 17:53:12.830  INFO 3008 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

This indicates that a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` is created to serve the `favicon.ico` file. However, `/blah/favicon.ico` can no longer be accessed.

Comment: What do you have under // various GET/POST path enable rules?

Comment: A long list of paths parameterized by `public static final String ...`, which is why I did not publish them. For the anonymous HttpMethod.GET, these paths certainly do not include the said `/blah/favicon.ico` that I used for the simple test. That path is clearly enabled by a default rule. Another test that I just tried was to access `/css/favicon.ico` -- since I use `/styles` instead of `/css`, it should have not succeeded but it did.

Comment: Have you looked at the Actuator to determine what auto-configuration may have added it? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Re-reading the docs I referenced above, the responsible component seems to be `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration`. Apparently, it can be controlled via `SecurityProperties` or via the externalized application properties (which, presumably means the security.ignored, which I could not get to work). So, I will try to experiment with a `SecurityProperties` bean.

Comment: I figured it out -- see update above.

Comment: You can achieve the same result by `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation at your `@Configuration` class

Comment: @user1408140 when you answer your own question you need to actually add an _answer_

Answer (score 0):

In your last antmatcher to be denied have specific urls withour having the single slash which will block all endpoints